# 'conda install into' downgrades packages why?

Tags: python, conda

I am trying to install 'into' package by using `conda install into`
in the way mentioned in the [link](https://github.com/blaze/blaze-tutorial/blob/master/01-into-Introduction.ipynb). Conda asks me to downgrade the following packages

> ```
> The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
>
>     astropy:      1.1.2-np110py27_0  --> 1.0.4-np19py27_0 
>     h5py:         2.6.0-np110py27_1  --> 2.5.0-np19py27_3 
>     hdf5:         1.8.16-0           --> 1.8.15.1-2       
>     libgfortran:  3.0.0-1            --> 3.0-0            
>     matplotlib:   1.5.1-np110py27_0  --> 1.4.3-np19py27_2 
>     mkl:          11.3.3-0           --> 11.3.1-0         
>     mkl-service:  1.1.2-py27_1       --> 1.1.2-py27_0     
>     numexpr:      2.5.2-np110py27_1  --> 2.4.4-np19py27_0 
>     numpy:        1.10.4-py27_2      --> 1.9.3-py27_2     
>     pandas:       0.18.1-np110py27_0 --> 0.17.1-np19py27_0
>     pyparsing:    2.1.1-py27_0       --> 2.0.3-py27_0     
>     pytables:     3.2.2-np110py27_3  --> 3.2.2-np19py27_0 
>     scikit-image: 0.12.3-np110py27_0 --> 0.11.3-np19py27_0
>     scikit-learn: 0.17.1-np110py27_1 --> 0.16.1-np19py27_0
>     scipy:        0.17.1-np110py27_0 --> 0.17.0-np19py27_2
> ```

Can anyone tell me if this is a normal thing? If yes then are the downgraded versions of these packages able to use intel's mkl library?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like almost everything is being altered based on numpy version 1.9 (np19py27_x). Since everything on the left is using numpy 1.10 it looks like the downgrades are in response to a requirement by into to use numpy 1.9. As far as whether the downgrades would work with the mkl library, you would have to check documentation or test it. I would recommend scouring the documentation for mkl library and creating a virtual environment for using into to ensure you don't foul up your default conda setup.